# Xbox thumbstick used to rotate sprite, basic formula makes it "stick" or feel "sticky" at 90 degree intervals! How do you get smooth rotation?

Tags: xna, c#, sprites, rotation, gamepad

I am using a very basic formula to calculate what angle my sprite (spaceship for example) should be facing based on the Xbox controller thumbstick i.e. you use the thumbstick to rotate the ship.

In my main update method:

```
shuttleAngle = (float) Math.Atan2(newGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Right.X, newGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y);
```

In my main draw method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(shuttle, shuttleCoords, sourceRectangle, Color.White, shuttleAngle, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

As you can see it's quite simple, I take the current radians from the thumbstick and store it in a float `shuttleAngle` and then use this as the rotation angle (in radians) argument for drawing the shuttle.

For some reason when I rotate the sprint it feels sticky at 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees angles.  It wants to settle at those angles. It's not giving me a smooth and natural rotation like I would feel in a game that uses a similar mechanic. PS: My Xbox controller is fine!

Comment: Doesn't Atan2 take the Y value first and then the X value?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx . You need to swap your x and y value first. Also have you considered easing your values by interpolation? toValue-currentValue / speed

Comment: Sorry I meant  newShuttleAngle - oldShuttleAngle / speed.

Comment: That would only effect the visual orientation and that depends entirely on which way the image for the texture is orientated - I can't see that affected his problem.

Comment: Is this Windows? If so set the project to use a console window (Project -> Project Options -> Application -> Output Type) and print out your angle `shuttleAngle` to see if that sticks at those angles

Comment: @Joe
It's still expected to use the y value first. He might shoot himself in the foot later on.

Comment: i havent tryed this interpolation yet, but it makes no sense it shouldnt stick to those angles, maybe its the way the xbox contoller is designed? i just tryed swapping the values and now for some reason its moved everything 90 degrees to the right, ie i point the thumbstick right and the shuttle points up, point it down and shuttle points right!

Comment: Well I guess that's because of your original orientation. You can leave your atan2 as is.

Comment: @Sidar I guess... but I find sometimes I get the result I want just by swapping them, I mean, the Y/X or X/Y order is only arbitrary

Comment: @Joe i am printing the angles to screen, they seem accurate, when i am "sticking" to for example 0 degrees and i move the stick a tiny bit left and right but the sprite doesnt budge, the value doesnt budge either, and its printing the full float

Comment: that to me makes it seem like its a feature of the controller! i am probly wrong though!

Comment: Have a look at SomeWritesReserved's answer, I have no experience with the 360 pad

Comment: wow great job SomeWritesReserved and everyone else, i am really impressed with this site, the feedback is so fast! its my first post so can someone please tell me what i need to do to properly credit all those who helped?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It might be because of how the GamePad's deadzone works. It defaults to `GamePadDeadZone.IndependentAxes`, which means each axis is checked against the dead zone individually. This tends to cause the input to snap to each axis of the analog thumbstick. Instead, try using `GamePadDeadZone.Circular`:

```
newGamePadState = GamePad.GetState(playerIndex, GamePadDeadZone.Circular);
```

This should give you much smoother control on both axes. Check out the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb200104%28v=xnagamestudio.41%29) and [this article by Shawn Hargreaves](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915141234/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/28/gamepads-suck.aspx).